# send free sms from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms, ruby-on-rails-3

How can i send free sms to US numbers from a rails app.

Is [sms_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu) working with rails 3?

Its not working for me :--
After installing the gem.

Steps:-
Specified this in my environment file

```
 1. sms_fu = SMSFu::Client.configure(:delivery => :action_mailer)
```

and then

```
2.sms_fu.deliver("5558675309","at&t","message") is not working
```

Comment: do you mean you're trying to deliver messages from your environment.rb?

Comment: @cam check the question again... and can u tell me one thing. How can one send message from Environment.rb and if somebody is trying to send. Whats the use case???

Comment: it doesn't make sense to send messages from environment.rb.  This is something that would most likely happen in your controller (or a background job).  Perhaps you should try [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, i can see this does not work for all providers (i am from Europe). So for me this is not a viable solution, although it seems very interesting.

To test it, i would recommend the following.

- add the gem to your `Gemfile`: `gem "sms_fu"`
- start up the rails console (`rails c`)
- inside the console type the two lines you typed, and see what happens

Inside your Rails-app, I would create the `sms_fu` variable inside an initializer (a file inside the `config/initializers` folder, and then inside any controller action, you can just do `sms_fu.deliver(...)`.

We use the paying sms-services from [Clickatell](http://clickatell.com) and [Tyntec](http://tyntec.com).

Comment: Its working from console. Can u please help me "where to initilize this sms_fu variable.". So that i can send sms from model or controller. I am talking about this sms_fu = SMSFu::Client.configure(:delivery => :action_mailer)

Comment: There is no file like initialize.rb in config/initializers folder

Comment: Any file inside the `config/initializers` is loaded at start-up. So create a file called `init_sms.rb` with the initialization line.

Comment: Ya tried that. But its not working. I am getting an error message like irb(main):001:0> sms_fu.deliver("5558675309","at&t","message")
NameError: undefined local variable or method `sms_fu' for main:Object
 from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [Twilio](http://twilio.com). NO, it's not free, but there are no reliable FREE SMS service APIs. SMS_fu just composes it as an email - that's why the carrier is required.

Twilio is cheap ($0.03/msg) and reliable. And it comes with more powerful tools and analytics.

NOTE: I'm in no way affiliated - just a fan of their service.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using SMS_FU for Rails 3.  Implement an SMS sender yourself.  It's simple, and  brendanlim no longer seems interested in supporting the sms_fu gem.