# Send free sms from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sms

Is there any good method/gem to send free sms for both national and international from rails application?

As i am staying in India, my mail focus is to sent sms in this country. But for future, i'll require international message send also.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use [sms_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu), [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983613/are-there-any-free-services-for-sending-sms-programmatically)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652755/send-free-sms-from-rails-app

Comment: Ref:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627326/send-sms-for-mobile-number-verification-clickatell-rails-3

Comment: but i am getting error while sending sms as,
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 7 column 12
 from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse'
 from /Users/apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'

Comment: any idea? why i am getting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smsgupshup.com provides api for that. You just have to make a request to their API to send an sms. Obviously they will charge you

Comment: are they provide any testdrive in development process? if yes can you please give me is procedure?

Comment: [API](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/help/in/enterprisesmsgupshup-api-document.html)

[Website](http://enterprise.smsgupshup.com/)

Hope these helps

Answer (score -1):

Try [fowiz](http://www.fowiz.com), an Android based solution for sending SMS from applications. Their API is HTTP based, you need an Android phone and the messages are sent from your device.

Find below

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('http://cloud.fowiz.com/api?
    username=yourusername&
    phonenumber=yourphonenumber&
    message=yourmessage&
    passcode=yourpasscode')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|http.request(req)}
puts res.body
```